# How to treat \t as a regular string in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace

I need to remove \t from a string that is being written however when ever I do

```
str(contents).replace('\t', ' ')
```

it just removes all of the tabs. I understand this is because \t is how you write tabs but I want to know how to just treat it like a regular string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prefix the string with `r` and create a [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

```
str(contents).replace(r'\t', ' ')
```

Raw-strings do not process escape sequences.  Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> mystr = r'a\t\tb'  # Escape sequences are ignored
>>> print(mystr)
a\t\tb
>>> print(mystr.replace('\t', ' '))  # This replaces tab characters
a\t\tb
>>> print(mystr.replace(r'\t', ' '))  # This replaces the string '\t'
a  b
>>>
```